Next.js won't update after running pnpm dev
I am following the tutorial on Next.js's website. In chapter 1, I am supposed to add "import '@/app/ui/global.css'" to the beginning of the layout.tsx file. after running pnpm dev the page did not update and stayed the same as before. About an hour after going in and out of visual studio code, the page was updated using pnpm dev. I again tried to update the page by adding a black triangle and removing a log that I previously added when importing the global.css. The same problem happened, the black triangle isn't there and the log is still there meaning the page isn't updating the changes to the script. I also do not know how I got the global.css to update, I tried replicating what got me there but it didn't work.
I have tried restarting my computer many times. I have also tried removing the .next folder but that did not change anything. The last thing I tried was using npm run dev instead of pnpm dev but that also produced the same result.
